# необходимо чтобы команда "show" выводила все задачи на все заданные даты, но у меня выдает ошибку Bad Request: me ssage text is empty

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
import random

token = ''

RANDOM_TASKS = ["Записаться на курс в Нетологию", "Написать Гвидо письмо", "Покормить кошку", "Помыть машину"]

HELP = """
/help - вывести справку о программе.
/add - добавить команду в список задач (/add дата + задача).
/show - вывести список задач (/show + дата).
/random - добавить случайную задачу на сегодня"""

tasks = {}

def add_todo(date, task):
 if date in tasks:
      tasks[date].append(task)
 else:
     tasks[date] = []
     tasks[date].append(task)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, HELP)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add(message):
    command = message.text.split(maxsplit=2)
    date = command[1].lower()
    task = command[2]
    add_todo(date, task)
    if len(task) < 3:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Задача должна быть длинее 3-х символов")
    else:
        text = ("Задача " + task + " добавлена на дату " + date)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['random'])
def random_add(message):
    date = 'сегодня'
    task = random.choice(RANDOM_TASKS)
    add_todo(date, task)
    text = ("Задача " + task + " добавлена на дату " + date)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["show", "print"])
def show(message):
    dates = ''
    text = ''
    tasks = ''
    for date in tasks:
        task = tasks.get(date)
        text += "*" + dates + "\n"
        for task in tasks:
            text += "*" + tasks + "\n"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```